# apache superset connecting to databricks delta lake

Tags: databricks, apache-superset, delta-lake

I am trying to read data from databricks delta lake via. apache superset. I can connect to delta lake with a JDBC connection string supplied by the cluster but superset seems to require a sql alchemy string so I'm not sure what I need to do to get this working. Thank you, anything helps

[superset database setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpjdE.png)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?
https://flynn.gg/blog/databricks-sqlalchemy-dialect/

> Thanks to contributions by Evan Thomas, the Python databricks-dbapi
> package now supports using Databricks as a SQL dialect within
> SQLAlchemy. This is particularly useful for hooking up Databricks to a
> dashboard frontend application like Apache Superset. It provides
> compatibility with both standard Databricks and Azure Databricks.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `pyhive` and you should be ready to connect to databricks thrift JDBC server.